# i have a problem with python 3.8.5's GUI Code

Tags: python, tkinter

ok so the problem is that i was following a tutorial from someone named "Dev Ed" and i made a gui with TKinter after going halfway into the tutorial i got this error "Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'filename' is not defined" here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os 

root = tk.Tk()
apps = []

def addApp():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
    filetypes=(("executables","*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))

apps.append(filename)
print(filenme)
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
    label.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#163542")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3, relx=0.35, rely=0.35)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10,
pady=5, fg="white", bg="#163542" ,command=addApp)

openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10,
pady=5)

runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

the error happened on line 12 or 13

Comment: These `apps.append(filename)` and `print(filenme)` should be inside the function `addApp`.

Comment: @Saad that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White space is very important in python. In your `addApp()` function the variable `filename` exists, but in the global space that `apps.append(filename)` was in it could not find it.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()
apps = []

def addApp():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
    filetypes=(("executables","*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    apps.append(filename)  # This appears to have been in the wrong spot.
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
        label.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#163542")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3, relx=0.35, rely=0.35)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10,
pady=5, fg="white", bg="#163542" ,command=addApp)

openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10,
pady=5)

runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i have a new problem on line 39 it gives me this error "name 'runApps' is not defined"

Comment: @Arhum You may need to start a new post as I don't even see a line 39 in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os 

  root = tk.Tk()
apps = []
 def addApp():

for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
filetypes=(("executables","*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))
apps.append(filename)
print(filename)
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
    label.pack()


    def runApps():
        for app in apps:
            os.startfile(app)




  canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#163542")
  canvas.pack()

  frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
   frame.place(relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.4, relx=0.3, rely=0.25)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10,
pady=5, fg="white", bg="#163542" ,command=addApp)

openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10,
pady=5 , fg="white", bg="#163542" , command = runApps)

runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

## this is my new code ShanyeLoyd

Comment: I really meant to start an entire new question. Your errors above are all in the white space. Your ```def runApps()``` actually only exists in your for loop. I would highly recommend you download PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/. It is free and it will help you with your syntax.